# AngularJS: Directive causes another directive to activate, causing errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this in a partial:

```
<div class="data" ng-keydown="handleKeys($event, $index)" ng-focus="handleFocus($event, $index)" contenteditable>{{data.text_content}}</div>
```

Everything worked beautifully with just the ng-keydown directive, but after adding the ng-focus directive, I keep getting "Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress".

handleKeys() actually sets the focus on the next/previous div if the key is arrow up/down, so my understanding is that handleFocus() is called while the $apply for handleKeys() is still in progress, causing the error.

Is there any way to avoid this, taking into account that I need to do stuff both on keydown and focus, and that handleKeys() needs to set the focus of some div.data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use $timeout to schedule the event for the next cycle:

```
$scope.handleKeys = function (event,index){
     if (event.which == 38){ //Up
         $timeout(function(){
           angular.element(event.target).prev().focus();
         });
     }

     if (event.which == 40){ //Down
       $timeout(function(){

         angular.element(event.target).next().focus();
       });
     }
  };
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/AB8GQrTFrh4OUddfO4Vx?p=preview)

Without $timeout, this [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Marr5GD0Mc3z6UinmuPe?p=preview) has the exact issue in your question and you're right that handleFocus() is called while the $apply for handleKeys() is still in progress

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I thought I had already tried that, but apparently not.